# Need to make the JavaFX embedded browser to work inside an action listener

Tags: javafx

I need to make the JavaFX window to open when I press a Jbutton. I've tried all kinds of ways, I've searched over the internet and I've found nothing. The libraries are correctly set, but is not working.

How can make this works ? thank a lot !

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class UTF8  {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        UTF8 object = new UTF8();
        object.UTF8();
    }

    public void UTF8() {
        JButton browser = new JButton();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(browser); frame.setSize(100,100); frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == browser) {

                    Scene scene;
                    TextField addressField;
                    WebView webView;
                    WebEngine webEngine;
                    Stage stage = null;
                    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
                    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

                    //The TextField for entering web addresses.
                    addressField = new TextField("Enter Web address here...");
                    addressField.setPrefColumnCount(50); //make the field at least 50 columns wide.
                    //Add all out navigation nodes to the vbox.
                    hBox.getChildren().addAll(addressField);
                    //Our weiv that display ther page.
                    webView = new WebView();

                    //the engine that manages our pages.
                    webEngine = webView.getEngine();
                    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webEngine.load("http://www.google.ro");
                    //our main app layout with 5 regions.
                    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                    root.setPrefSize(1280, 720);
                    //Add every node to the BorderPane.
                    root.setTop(hBox);
                    root.setCenter(webView);
                    //Our scene is where all the action in JavaFX happens.  A scene holds all Nodes, and its root node is our BorderPane.
                    scene = new Scene(root);
                    //the stage manages the scene.
                    stage.setTitle("Ionutz Asaftei Browser");
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two UI libraries, which makes things tricky. Ideally you should use either all Swing, or all JavaFX. If you cannot do this, e.g. if you have an existing Swing application which you cannot readily rewrite and want to incorporate some JavaFX functionality, then I *strongly recommend* using window objects from only one toolkit, and using either [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) to embed FX content in a Swing window, or [`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) to embed Swing content into a FX `Stage`.

In this case, you should probably use a `JFXPanel` and open a new `JFrame` to contain it.

The reason your code won't work as it stands is, firstly, that you are trying to create a JavaFX scene graph when the FX toolkit has not been started, and secondly, that you are creating and showing a `Stage` from a thread that is not the FX Application Thread.

You can do

```
    browser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == browser) {

                // create a JFXPanel, which will start the FX toolkit
                // if it's not already started:
                JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Scene scene;
                    TextField addressField;
                    WebView webView;
                    WebEngine webEngine;
                    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
                    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

                    //The TextField for entering web addresses.
                    addressField = new TextField("Enter Web address here...");
                    addressField.setPrefColumnCount(50); //make the field at least 50 columns wide.
                    //Add all out navigation nodes to the vbox.
                    hBox.getChildren().addAll(addressField);
                    //Our weiv that display ther page.
                    webView = new WebView();

                    //the engine that manages our pages.
                    webEngine = webView.getEngine();
                    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webEngine.load("http://www.google.ro");
                    //our main app layout with 5 regions.
                    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                    root.setPrefSize(1280, 720);
                    //Add every node to the BorderPane.
                    root.setTop(hBox);
                    root.setCenter(webView);
                    //Our scene is where all the action in JavaFX happens.  A scene holds all Nodes, and its root node is our BorderPane.
                    scene = new Scene(root);
                    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                });
                JFrame browserFrame = new JFrame();
                browserFrame.add(fxPanel);
                browserFrame.setTitle("Ionutz Asaftei Browser");
                browserFrame.setSize(1280, 720);
                browserFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked !!!!!! Yesterday i've thought i will go nuts. I've spend about 5 hours or more to search for a solution, tried different ways but without results. This example is perfect. I'm a beginner in programming, and when i got time, i'm playing with Netbeans and Java, i don't have your knowlegde :) . Thanks again for the explanations and very easy example. You guys are great, the best, can't thank you enough. Great community, great people.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm), if you haven't have already.

In your case, you need to use a [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) as an intermediate node which accepts a JavaFX Scene as its content and extends JComponent, which helps you to set it to a JFrame as a component.

Set all your JavaFX content into the scene's root and then add the scene to this JFXPanel using `jfxpanel.setScene()`. *You need to do it on JavaFX application thread* i.e. wrap it around `Platform.runLater()`.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;


public class UTF8  {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        UTF8 object = new UTF8();
        object.UTF8();
    }

    public void UTF8() {

        JButton browser = new JButton("Click me");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(browser);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (e.getSource() == browser) {
                JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    initFX(jfxPanel);
                });
                JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
                newFrame.setSize(300, 200);
                newFrame.setContentPane(jfxPanel);
                newFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        TextField addressField;
        WebView webView;
        WebEngine webEngine;
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //The TextField for entering web addresses.
        addressField = new TextField("Enter Web address here...");
        addressField.setPrefColumnCount(50); //make the field at least 50 columns wide.
        //Add all out navigation nodes to the vbox.
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(addressField);
        //Our weiv that display ther page.
        webView = new WebView();

        //the engine that manages our pages.
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.ro");
        //our main app layout with 5 regions.
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPrefSize(1280, 720);
        //Add every node to the BorderPane.
        root.setTop(hBox);
        root.setCenter(webView);
        //Our scene is where all the action in JavaFX happens.  A scene holds all Nodes, and its root node is our BorderPane.
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        //the stage manages the scene.
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will read it very carefully. If it wasn't for you guys, i would spend another day trying to figure out a solution (and mostly sure, without success). Thanks again, it worked just perfect! :)